# Evaluate the integrals $\int_{\gamma}z^{n}dz$ for all integers $n$.

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

> Evaluate the integrals
>   $$\int_{\gamma}z^{n}dz$$
>   for all integers $n$. Here $\gamma$ is any circle centered at the origin with the positive (counterclockwise) orientation.

I don't know how to proceed. I couldn't find a "quick" way to do this, so I thought I'd use induction over $n$, but it seems like unnecessary work. Is there a clever way to calculate this integral?

**My attempt.** $z(t) = re^{it}$, so
$$\int_{\gamma}z^{n}dz = \int_{0}^{2\pi}(re^{it})^{n}ire^{it}dt = ir^{n+1}\int_{0}^{2\pi}(e^{it})^{n+1}dt.$$

Comment: Hint: for positive $n$, the integral is zero because Cauchy.

Comment: Now find the antiderivative. The case $n = -1$ is special.

Comment: @SeanRoberson, it's true, but I still cannot use this

Comment: @HansEngler, $\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{e^{it(n+1)}}{i(n+1)}\right) = \frac{e^{it(n+1)}i(n+1)}{i(n+1)} = (e^{it})^{n+1}$, right? If $n \neq -1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your work looks perfectly good to me, you just need to finish it. If $n \neq -1$, then $n+1 \neq 0$, so $\int_0^{2 \pi} (e^{it})^{n+1} = 0$ (why?) If $n=-1$, then your reasoning shows the result is $ i \int_0^{2 \pi} 1 dz = 2 \pi i $.

Comment: I think I got it! If $n \neq -1$ so, $\int_{0}^{2\pi}(e^{it})^{n+1}dt = \frac{e^{it(n+1)}}{i(n+1)}|_{0}^{2\pi}$, right?

Comment: Yeah, that looks good to me