# Integrate $\int_{\gamma} z^{n}$ where $\gamma$ is any circle not containing the origin.

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I want to generalize this question: [Evaluate the integrals $\int_{\gamma}z^{n}dz$ for all integers $n$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2908226/evaluate-the-integrals-int-gammazndz-for-all-integers-n)

I mean: the same question but with $\gamma$ any circle not containing the origin. Then if $\gamma$ has radius $r$, we can write a parameterization $z(t) = c + re^{it}$ with $c > r$. So, the integral becomes
$$\int(c+re^{it})^{n}ire^{it}dt$$
I think maybe I should use some "trick" taking advantage of the case of the circle centered on the origin. Can someone help me?

Comment: You may use binomial theorem, or easier way is to use residue theorem. The answer depends on the location of origin with respect to the circle. In your case, the answer shiuld be 0.

Comment: Do you know Cauchy's theorem? If $\Delta$ is a disk and $0 \notin \overline \Delta$ then $z^n$ is analytic on a neighborhood of $\Delta$ so $\int_{\partial \Delta} z^n \, dz =$ ...?

Comment: The residuet theorem and Cauchy theorem give elegant proofs, but both were proved in the later chapter. Use the binomial theorem was my first thought, but it seemed a laborious one. But I think now, in applying the theorem, I'm going to get several integrals similar to the previous problem, right?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you can deal with $n\geq 0$. For negative $n$'s, you may use generalized binomial theorem: for $|z|<1$ and $m\geq 1$, we have
$$
(1+z)^{-m} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{-m}{k} z^{k} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{k} \binom{m+k-1}{k}z^{k}
$$
Which converges absolutely. 
Then we have
$$
\int_{0}^{2\pi} (c+re^{it})^{-m}ire^{it}dt = c^{-m}ir\int_{0}^{2\pi}\left(1+ \frac{re^{it}}{c}\right)^{-m}e^{it}dt = c^{-m}ir\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{k}\binom{m+k-1}{k}\frac{r^{k}}{c^{k}}\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{i(k+1)t}dt =0
$$
Note that $c>r$ is important here: for $r>c$, the integral should be
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{2\pi} (c+re^{it})^{-m}ire^{it}dt &= r^{-m}ir\int_{0}^{2\pi}\left(1+ \frac{ce^{-it}}{r}\right)^{-m}e^{i(1+m)t}dt\\
&= r^{-m+1}i\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{k}\binom{m+k-1}{k}\frac{r^{k}}{c^{k}}\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{i(m+1-k)t}dt \\
&=\begin{cases} 0 & m >1 \\ 2\pi i & m=1, k=0\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Comment: Do you want "Note that $c > r$ . . . "?

Comment: @RobertLewis I changed it. Thanks!

Comment: Hi! I appreciate your answer, but here's one question, shouldn't it be (1-m) in the first RHS of the last equation? $(c+re^{it})^{-m}=(r(\frac{c}{r}+e^{it}))^{-m}=(re^{it}(\frac{c}{r}e^{-it}+1))^{-m}=r^{-m}e^{i(-m)t}(\frac{c}{r}e^{-it}+1)^{-m}$; and thus we have $e^{i(k+1-m)t}$ in the second RHS, under which I think your conclusion would then hold.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see why Cauchy's theorem or the residue formula are needed here.

First of all, suppose

$n \ne -1; \tag 1$

then the function

$F_n(z) = \dfrac{z^{n + 1}}{n + 1} \tag 2$

is everywhere a primitive for $z^n$:

$F'_n(z) = \left (  \dfrac{z^{n + 1}}{n + 1} \right )' = z^n, \; \forall z \in \Bbb C; \tag 3$

it is then elementary that, for $z_0, z \in \Bbb C$,

$\dfrac{z^{n + 1}}{n + 1} - \dfrac{z_0^{n + 1}}{n + 1} = \displaystyle \int_{z_0}^z F'_n(w) \; dw = \int_{z_0}^z w^n \; dw; \tag 4$

for any closed path $\gamma(t)$ in $\Bbb C$,

$\gamma:[a, b] \to \Bbb C, \; \gamma(a) = \gamma(b) = z_0, \tag 5$

since $\gamma(t)$ both starts and ends at $z_0$, (4) becomes

$\displaystyle \int_\gamma w^n \; dw = \dfrac{z_0^{n + 1}}{n + 1} - \dfrac{z_0^{n + 1}}{n + 1} = 0; \tag 6$

taking

$w = \gamma(t) = c + r e^{it}, \; t \in [0, 2\pi], \tag 7$

we recover the specific case

$\displaystyle \int_\gamma (c + re^{it})^n rie^{it} \; dt = \int_0^{2\pi} (c + re^{it})^n rie^{it} \; dt = 0, n \ne -1; \tag 8$

when $n = -1$, the expression (2) cannot yield a primitive for $f(z) = z^{-1}$, since then $n + 1 = 0$; in the light of the hypothesis that $r < c$, however, we may set

$F_{-1}(z) = \ln z \tag 9$

in an open disk $D(c, c + \epsilon)$, $\epsilon < c - r$; then

$F'_{-1}(z) = \dfrac{1}{z} \tag{10}$

in $D(c, c + \epsilon)$, so essentially the same argument as in (4), (6) applies; for
$z_0, z \in D(c, c + \epsilon)$,

$\ln z - \ln z_0 = \displaystyle \int_{z_0}^z F'_{-1}(w) \; dw = \int_{z_0}^z \dfrac{dw}{w}; \tag{11}$

$\displaystyle \int_\gamma \dfrac{dw}{w} = \ln z_0 - \ln z_0 = 0, \tag{12}$

$\gamma(t)$ a closed path in $D(c, c + \epsilon)$.